# Update Select with Ajax & Jquery based on another select

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, html-select

I'm having trouble figuring out how to update a second select box based on the value chosen for the first. I need to use a hardcoded JSON for the second select options.

HTML:

```
    Makes:
    <select id="make" name="make" onchange="changeMake(this);">
        <option disabled="" selected="">Select Make</option>
        <option value="audi">Audi</option>
        <option value="mercedes">Mercedes-Benz</option>
        <option value="tesla">Tesla</option>            
    </select>
    <br>
    Models:
    <select id="model" name="model">        
    </select>
```

JS:

```
    var cars = [
                    {"Makes" : [
                        {"make": "audi", "models": ["A7","A8","R8"]}
                        {"make": "audi", "models": ["G-Class SUV","SLS-Class Coupe","C-Class Sedan"]}
                        {"make": "tesla", "models": ["Roadster","Model S","Model X"]}
                    ]}
                ];
  function changeMake(sel) {
     var selected_make = sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].value; 
     var select_model = document.getElementById('model');
     select.options.length = 0; 
     $.each(cars, function(data) {
         var options = cars.options;
         for (var i = 0; i < options.length;; i++) {
              var option = options.make[selected_make].models;
              select_model.options.add(new Option(option.models[i], option.models[i]));

          }
    });
}
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ND2NC/

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way of solving your issue. I changed your hardcoded `cars` json to something that is a little easier to use.

```
var cars = {
    audi: ["A7","A8","R8"],
    mercedes: ["G-Class SUV","SLS-Class Coupe","C-Class Sedan"],
    tesla: ["Roadster","Model S","Model X"]
};
```

Here's the rest of the function:

```
function clearSelect(sel){
    var i;
    for(i=sel.options.length-1; i>=0; i--){
        sel.remove(i);
    }
}

function changeMake(sel) {
    var selected_make = sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].value; 
    var select_model = document.getElementById('model');

    // Remove all select options
    clearSelect(select_model);

    // Loop through each model of the selected make
    $.each(cars[selected_make], function(index, model) {
        // Create select option
        var option = document.createElement("option");
        option.text = model;
        option.value = model;
        // Add option to select
        select_model.options.add(option);
    });
}
```

Note: this uses a lot of javascript, which is what you had before. You can do the same thing with less javascript and more jQuery.

[Link to Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MeZkM/)